# Javascript - re-order Array of Objects (value) by Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an Array of Objects:

```
data = [
  {
    type: "displayName"
    base: {}
    staged: {}
  },
  {
    type: "bots"
    base: {}
    staged: {}
  },
  {
    type: "bots"
    base: {}
    staged: {}
  },
  {
    type: "whiteList"
    base: {}
    staged: {}
  }
]
```

I then have a array I would like to use to order my `data` array:

```
order = ["bots", "whiteList", "displayName"]
```

I need to order `data` based off each objects `type`

I have tried:

```
private orderChanges = (data: any[], order: any[]) => {
    const orderedArray = [];
    let len = Object.keys(data).length;

    for (; len-- ;) {
      const current = data[len];
      const index = order.indexOf(current.resourceType);
      orderedArray[index] = current;
    }

    return orderedArray;
  }
```

While this works is will only return a single type->bots object in orderedArray.

Thanks!

Comment: btw, `'whitelist'` is different from `'whiteList'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent wheels, just `.sort` :

```
  data.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(b.type) - order.indexOf(a.type));
```

That takes two elements (`a` and `b`) of the array, gets the indices of their `type` inside the `order` array, and returns the difference of those indices back to the sorting function. Three things might happen:

1) Both got the same order: They therefore also got the same index and the difference is `0`, the sorting algorithm keeps them at the same position.

2) A's type is earlier in the order array, the index is lower, the difference is positive and therefore the algorithm will swap both elements so that A is first.

2) B's type is earlier, B will be moved to the first position.

That is repeated with all elements in the array until they are completely sorted.

Comment: Definitely don't want to and I felt as though I was so that is why I asked.

Comment: @ardz good decision ;)